# Google Achievements Unlock But Don't Save

Tags: android, google-play, achievements

I added achievements to my Google Play game following Google's tutorial. They unlock fine and if I display achievements in-game immediately they show up. If I quit the game and go to the Google Game's app they don't show up and they disappear from in-game also. Any ideas? I've tried multiple accounts. Thanks!

```
package com.b1stable.tth;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.PathMatcher;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.util.Vector;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Build;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.os.VibrationEffect;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.Gravity;

import org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity; 

import com.b1stable.tth.License_Viewer_Activity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.games.AchievementsClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.AnnotatedData;
import com.google.android.gms.games.EventsClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.android.gms.games.GamesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.LeaderboardsClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Player;
import com.google.android.gms.games.PlayersClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.event.Event;
import com.google.android.gms.games.event.EventBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task.*;

public class TTH_Activity extends SDLActivity
{
    final static int LICENSE_REQUEST = 1;

    native static void resume_after_showing_license();
    native static void resume_after_showing_achievements();
    native static void pause();
    native static void resume();

    // Client used to sign in with Google APIs
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private AchievementsClient mAchievementsClient = null;
    private boolean signin_failed = false;

    // request codes we use when invoking an external activity
    private static final int RC_UNUSED = 5001;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

    // This is so the screen is never cleared pure black, only shim::black (r:35, g:30, b:60)
    static boolean paused = false;

     private static final String TAG = "TTH";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == LICENSE_REQUEST) {
            if (data != null) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data.getExtras().getString("MESSAGE").equals("OK")) {
                    show_license_result = 0;
                }
                else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && data.getExtras().getString("MESSAGE").equals("FAIL")) {
                    show_license_result = 1;
                }
                else {
                    show_license_result = 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                show_license_result = 1;
            }

            resume_after_showing_license();
        }
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                // The signed in account is stored in the result.
                GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
                onConnected(signedInAccount);
            }
            else {
                String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
                if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
                    message = "An error occurred!";
                }
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message).setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
                onDisconnected();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
        pause();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onRestart()
    {
        super.onRestart();
        resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        signInSilently();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        mAchievementsClient = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostResume()
    {
        super.onPostResume();
        paused = true;
    }

    public void logString(String s)
    {
        Log.d("TTH", s);
    }

    public String getAppdataDir()
    {
        return getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    }
    
    public String getSDCardDir()
    {
        File f = getExternalFilesDir(null);
        if (f != null) {
            return f.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        else {
            return getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }

    static int show_license_result;

    public void showLicense()
    {
        show_license_result = -1;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, License_Viewer_Activity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, LICENSE_REQUEST);
    }

    public int getShowLicenseResult()
    {
        return show_license_result;
    }

    /*
    public void openURL(String url)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    */

    public void rumble(int milliseconds)
    {
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if (v != null && v.hasVibrator()) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(milliseconds, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
            }
            else {
                v.vibrate(milliseconds);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean has_touchscreen()
    {
        return getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature("android.hardware.touchscreen");
    }

    public boolean has_vibrator()
    {
        Vibrator v = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        if (v != null) {
            return v.hasVibrator();
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void start_draw()
    {
        if (paused) {
            paused = false;
        }
    }
    
    public String get_android_language()
    {
        return Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    }

    private static File[] list_dir_files = null;

    public void list_dir_start(String path)
    {
        try {
            int slash = path.lastIndexOf('/');
            final String glob = path.substring(slash+1).replace("*", ".*"); // +1 works even if not found (-1+1 == 0)
            String dir = path.substring(0, slash);
            File f = new File(dir);
            list_dir_files = f.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File f)
                {
                    try {
                        if (f.getName().matches(glob)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("TTH", "list_dir_start FileFilter throwing " + e.getMessage());
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            list_dir_files = null;
            Log.d("TTH", "list_dir_start throwing " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public String list_dir_next()
    {
        if (list_dir_files == null) {
            return "";
        }
        else if (list_dir_files.length == 0) {
            list_dir_files = null;
            return "";
        }
        else {
            File f = list_dir_files[0];
            String name = f.getName();
            if (list_dir_files.length == 1) {
                list_dir_files = null;
            }
            else {
                File[] new_list = new File[list_dir_files.length-1];
                for (int i = 1; i < list_dir_files.length; i++) {
                    new_list[i-1] = list_dir_files[i];
                }
                list_dir_files = new_list;
            }
            return name;
        }
    }

    private static final String ARC_DEVICE_PATTERN = ".+_cheets|cheets_.+";

    public boolean is_chromebook()
    {
        // Google uses this, so should work?
        return Build.DEVICE != null && Build.DEVICE.matches(ARC_DEVICE_PATTERN);
    }

    private static final int RC_ACHIEVEMENT_UI = 9003;

    public boolean show_achievements()
    {
        if (mAchievementsClient == null) {
            return false;
        }
        mAchievementsClient.getAchievementsIntent().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Intent>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Intent intent) {
                startActivityForResult(intent, RC_ACHIEVEMENT_UI);
                resume_after_showing_achievements();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception e) {
                resume_after_showing_achievements();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Intent>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<Intent> task) {
                resume_after_showing_achievements();
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
    
    public void achieve(String id)
    {
        if (mAchievementsClient != null) {
            mAchievementsClient.unlock(id);
        }
    }

    private void startSignInIntent() {
        GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
        Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    private void signInSilently() {
        if (signin_failed == true || mAchievementsClient != null) {
            return;
        }

        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN;
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        if (GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(account, signInOptions.getScopeArray())) {
            // Already signed in.
            // The signed in account is stored in the 'account' variable.
            //GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = account;
            onConnected(account);
        }
        else {
            // Haven't been signed-in before. Try the silent sign-in first.
            GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
            signInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(
                this,
                new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // The signed in account is stored in the task's result.
                            GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = task.getResult();
                            onConnected(signedInAccount);
                        }
                        else {
                            // Player will need to sign-in explicitly using via UI.
                            // See [sign-in best practices](http://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist) for guidance on how and when to implement Interactive Sign-in,
                            // and [Performing Interactive Sign-in](http://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin#performing_interactive_sign-in) for details on how to implement
                            // Interactive Sign-in.
                            startSignInIntent();
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }

    public void start_google_play_games_services() {
        /*
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                signInSilently();
            }
        });
        */
    }

    private void onConnected(GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected(): connected to Google APIs");

        GamesClient gamesClient = Games.getGamesClient(this, googleSignInAccount);
        gamesClient.setViewForPopups(findViewById(android.R.id.content));
        gamesClient.setGravityForPopups(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        mAchievementsClient = Games.getAchievementsClient(this, googleSignInAccount);
    }

    private void onDisconnected() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDisconnected()");

        mAchievementsClient = null;

        signin_failed = true;
    }
}
```